# How to remove annoying headings above regular headings?

Tags: excel

There are to row headings that won't go away. Here:[image: These mother f]

Comment: Goto Data tab and click on Ungroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows you have grouped columns.

Click `Data` > `Ungroup` > `Columns`